# build retention using jfrog for multi-configuration project

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, cloudbees, jfrog-cli

I have multi-configuration project in Jenkins which creates an artifact and uploads it to artifactory server using jFrog CLI command.
I need to add build retention period during uploading using jFrog CLI command.

Have tried following commands but none worked:

```
./jfrog rt u *.tar.bz2 ${BLR_ARTIFACTORY_TEST_REPO}/test/${BUILD_NUMBER}/ --url ${BLR_ARTIFACTORY_URL} --user=${AUTOMATION_USER} --password=${AUTOMATION_PWD}*
```

The above command uploads successfully and

```
./jfrog rt bdi test --delete-artifacts=true --url ${BLR_ARTIFACTORY_URL} --user=${AUTOMATION_USER} --password=${AUTOMATION_PWD} --max-builds=1 --max-days=1
```

The above command run and displays "Discarding builds.. Builds discarded." but build is not deleted from repository.

Need command for multi-configuration job using jfrog. Tried with pipeline job and it is working fine. Facing issue with Multi-Configuration job only.

Comment: I am assuming you are running the JFrog CLI via shell so the fact it is ran through a mutli-configuration project should be irrelevant, the commands should work. A few questions:
1. Did you publish the build after uploading with 'jfrog rt bp'?
2. Do you see the build published under 'builds' in artifactory?  
Also, The flag --max-days is optional. Dont use if you'd like to discard a build that was published the same day (or use --max-days=-1).

Comment: Hi @RadioJava, 
1. I uploaded builds and then ran 'jfrog rt bdi' as mentioned above.
2. I can see the builds in artifactory but they do not purge automatically after mentioned day.

Comment: You need to publish the build after uploading artifacts, using jfrog rt bp. Read more about build integration here:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-Overview.1

Comment: --max-days=-1 does it not mean infinite number of days ?